Prevent/remove null values in array as result of JOLT transform
I have a large payload for a complex (for me :-) JOLT transformation spec that gives empty/null values in the end result. Since the input, spec and output are quite big I have provided pastebin links. Hope this is OK.
Input is:
input
JOLT transform spec is:
JOLT spec
Result is:
output
Part that is not as we want is the pim_network part as shown below (the 2 empty asset_id ones, they are caused by null values after the 4th shift operation):
  "pim_network": [
    {
      "ifindex": 1,
      "ip_address": "127.0.0.1",
      "ip_subnet": 8,
      "description": "lo",
      "mac_address": "00:00:00:00:00:00",
      "asset_id": ""
    },
    {
      "asset_id": ""
    },
    {
      "ifindex": 2,
      "ip_address": "192.168.119.129",
      "ip_subnet": 24,
      "description": "ens33",
      "mac_address": "00:0c:29:02:b8:cd",
      "asset_id": ""
    },
    {
      "asset_id": ""
    },
    {
      "ifindex": 3,
      "ip_address": "172.17.0.1",
      "ip_subnet": 16,
      "description": "docker0",
      "mac_address": "02:42:36:ae:50:55",
      "asset_id": ""
    },
    {
      "ifindex": 4,
      "ip_address": "172.18.0.1",
      "ip_subnet": 16,
      "description": "br-c75ac7c3061d",
      "mac_address": "02:42:aa:97:1e:97",
      "asset_id": ""
    }
  ],

Expected result is that we only have the 4 valid IPv4 entries in the overall result. Hope somebody can assist.
P.S. I know JSON is not 100% properly visually formatted. Unfortunatelty this is what we get as output from the JOLT demo site.


As much as I can observe, the usage of modify-default-beta is
redundant. The pair "asset_id" : "" won't be generated if this spec is removed
The identifier [#2] should be replaced by &3 whenever the
attributes under the pim_network node are picked. The [#2] should be applied within the upcoming spec

As a result, you might shorten the transformation through use of the folowing one
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&",
        "pim_network": {
          "*": {
            "*": "&",
            "addresses": {
              "*": {
                "*": "&4.&1.others.&",
                "addr_info": {
                  "*": {
                    "*": "&6.&3.&2[&1].&"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "pim_network": {
        "*": {
          "addr_info": {
            "*": {
              "@2,others": { "*": "&5.&4_&2.&" },
              "*": "&4.&3_&1.&"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "pim_network": {
        "*": {
          "family": {
            "inet": {
              "@2,ifindex": "&4.&3.ifindex",
              "@2,local": "&4.&3.ip_address",
              "@2,prefixlen": "&4.&3.ip_subnet",
              "@2,label": "&4.&3.description",
              "@2,address": "&4.&3.mac_address"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "pim_hostname": {
        "SHORT_HOSTNAME": "hostname"
      },
      "pim_distro": {
        "PRETTY_NAME": "os_type"
      },
      "pim_hardware": {
        "processor_count": "cpu_count",
        "hw_memory": "memory"
      },
      "pim_storage": {
        "*": {
          "NAME": "&2[&1].drive_name",
          "SIZE": "&2[&1].capacity",
          "TYPE": "&2[&1].type_enum"
        }
      },
      "pim_network": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2[#2].&"
        }
      },
      "pim_software": {
        "*": {
          "Name": "&2[&1].name",
          "Version": "&2[&1].version"
        }
      },
      "pim_services": {
        "*": {
          "Id": "&2[&1].&",
          "Names": "&2[&1].name",
          "Description": "&2[&1].friendly_name",
          "LoadState": "&2[&1].loadstate",
          "ActiveState": "&2[&1].state",
          "UnitFileState": "&2[&1].unitfilestate",
          "UnitFilePreset": "&2[&1].start_mode"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]


Thanks once again Barbaros for solving our issue. To be precise: adding the asset_id key does not result in the "empty" objects. They are simply added to the null value objects from before. This can be seen by stripping of operations and looking at the output, you will then see the null values. Hope this makes sense, but not important at all :-).
